# Should answer to a complex equation be simply a linear system of real and imaginary parts $x$ and $y$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let's say I have an equation: $z^3+8=0$. Then if $z=x+yi$ I get an equation in the form: $$(x+yi)^3 +8 = (x+yi)(x^2+2xyi - y^2) +8 = x^3 -xy^2 -2xy^2 + 8 + (3x^2y - y^3)i$$ So to rewrite it as a linear system we get that $f(z) = \begin{matrix} u(x;y) = x^3 -3xy^3 + 8 \\ v(x;y) = 3x^2y - y^3 \end{matrix}$

So, is this the solution or do I need to find $x$ and $y$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to continue solving $x$ and $y$ from the system of equations

$$ x^3 -3xy^2 + 8=0\tag 1$$
$$ 3x^2y - y^3=0 \tag 2$$

From (2), we get $y=0$ or $y=\pm\sqrt3 x$. Plug them into (1) to obtain the solutions

$$(x,y) = (-2,0),\>(1,\pm\sqrt3)$$

Thus, the complex number solutions are $z= -2,\>1\pm\sqrt3 i$.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this specific equation is better found by writing $z$ in polar form - and it then becomes very simple. Let $z = r e^{i \theta}$ : then $z^3 = r^3 e^{3i \theta}$. Equating arguments and modules we get $r = 2$ and $\theta = \frac {\pi}{3}$ or $\frac{3 \pi}{3}$ or $\frac{5\pi}{3}$ (up to a multiple of $2 \pi$).

From which you can then deduce, if needed, the $x$s and $y$s.